# Guardar resultado en archivo de texto

Tags: python, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Hola que tal nuevamente,

Teniendo una url como la siguiente (pagina web dinamica) se refresca automaticamente cada 5 min:

```
url = 'http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&pc=21'
```

Donde el ultimo valor es variable, es decir un numero entre 1 al 1000 algo así:

```
url = 'http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&pc=21'
url = 'http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&pc=28'
url = 'http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&pc=44'
url = 'http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&pc=53'
url = 'http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&pc=88'
```

Necesito recorrer esa url cada vez que la página se refresca, y guardar el resultado del Scraping en un archivo de texto .csv

El ultimo valor puedo guardarlo manualmente en un archivo de texto o .csv y que de ahí python tome los datos.

Pero, tengo problemas para guardar los datos he intentado con esto y me tira error:

```
archivo = open("datos.txt", “w”)
archivo.write(codigos)
archivo.close()
```

Y lo primero recorrer las url no se si es posible lograrlo y no se como hacerlo Por otra parte al ser una página dinámica quizás exista una opción mas eficiente de realizar el proceso capturar los JSON que actualizan la página?

Espero puedan ayudarme u orientarme por donde empezar a investigar.

Codigo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import 
DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pickle


desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
desired_capabilities["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = 
webdriver.Chrome('/Users/JDani/Documents/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'http://mi.dominio.net/Operaciones/Reportes? 
server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx&pc=21'
driver.get(url)

try:
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
"ValorCorte")))
except TimeoutException:
print('Nope')
else:
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ValorCorte")
codigos = [element.text for element in content]

print(codigos)
```

Saludos

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear una carpeta lo hago de la siguiente manera:

## Si no existe la carpeta, la crea.

```
import os 
directorio = "C:/test"
try:
    os.stat(directorio)
except:
    os.mkdir(directorio)
```

## crear un .txt y escribir

```
file = open(directorio+"/myText.txt", "w")
file.write("SCRAPER   |   ESTADO" + os.linesep)
file.write("---------------------"+ os.linesep)
file.close()
```

## Abriendo y agregando datos

```
file = open(directorio+"/myText.txt", "a")
file.write("mas datos" + os.linesep)
file.write("aa"+ os.linesep)
file.close()
```

para guardar los datos primero lo paso a `DataFrame`. y luego lo guardo en un excel.

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
writer = ExcelWriter('C:/myexcel.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,'Hoja1')
writer.save()
```

Espero que te sirvan

Comment: He probado ambas funciones y me tiran error:

    '''df = pd.DataFrame(codigos)
    writer = ExcelWriter('C:/test/myexcel.xlsx')<--Aqui me tira error
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save()'''
    file = open(mipath+"/mytext.txt","w")
    file.write(codigos+os.linesep) <--- Aqui me tira el error
    file.close()

Cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: Prueba de esta manera `ExcelWriter('./a.xlsx')` . En el comentario agregue `import pandas as pd`. y en `file.write()`  intenta poner `str(codigos)`. Al poner `./` el .xlsx se guardará en la misma carpeta de tus scripts

Comment: En Excel me arroja este error:
    writer = ExcelWriter('./a.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\JDani\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1204, in __init__
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

file.write(str(codigos))
Si funciono, una pregunta mas referente a esta ultima linea como puedo agregar mas datos en el mismo archivo? No sobre escribirlo.

Comment: Al parecer no tienes instalado `openpyxl `. Para agregar más datos.. podes abrir el fichero con `"a"`. Sino  `file.write("otra linea.." + os.linesep)`

Comment: Es correcto ya funciona
Para agregar registros al archivo de texto no sobre escribir el existente estoy haciendo esto:
file.write('\n' + str(codigos))
Pero me sobre escribe el registro, que puede estar mal?

Comment: Perdón. ¿Necesitas agregar registros al fichero? o ¿Necesitas sobreescribirlo?

Comment: Agregar registros

Comment: `file = open(directorio+"/myText.txt", "a") ` Si abres el fichero de esa manera, debería agregar registros, a = append . w = write

Comment: Excelente!!!!, gracias por la ayuda Lucas Damian